# CSS mouse leave selector

Tags: css, html, button, transition

I'm using CSS to resize a button (image) when it is clicked:

```
.button:active{

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

however I not found any way to do it in a decent cross-browser way.

**Chrome**:

If I click the image (and keep clicked) and then I move the mouse out, the image is correctly resized to original size, BUT if I stop clicking when mouse is over a 2nd image that 2nd image get resized too.

**Firefox**:

If I click the image (and keep clicked) and then I mouve the mouse out, the image stays mignified.

Anyway to create buttons with "on mouse down" transition for image using only CSS?

I'm getting crazy. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, browser interpretation is still inconsistent when it comes to advanced use of `:active`.

Comment: *stop clicking when mouse is over a 2nd image* how can I redo this? As I understand I have to drag the mouse (keep the mouse down) over the second image and release the mouse there? That kind of action is considerred as *drag and drop*, at least Opera treats it that way. So there is nothing like the so-called *stop clicking on the 2nd image*. Conclusively, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I believe you are correct King King (Correct me if I'm wrong DarioOO). After dragging/dropping one image over another, the image will return full size in Chrome, but will remain resized in Firefox. Reproduced: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrimsrud/b6V86/).

Comment: Yes King, that's exactly what I meant, I don't have Opera so I not tried on it, only Firefox and Chrome. I think there's something obscure anyway, because certain gestures are not compatible (or you make a button like "OK" of window forms, or you make a draggable item, not both). So no solution for that eh? arrr... Using a javascript that "reset" properties periodically or at least is called when mouse exit(I know I asked for CSS, but seems there's no solution sigh)?

Comment: @DarioOO I think you may have to use script to disable the drag-n-drop operation on the buttons like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/pu8QU/4/